# How to get several cells coordinates taking as a reference 1 number in another cell

Tags: excel, google-sheets

I have the following code in a cell: `="&References!B7&"//"&References!B8&"//"&References!B9&"//"&References!B10&"//"&References!B11&"&mejor="&References!C7&"//"&References!C8&"//"&References!C9&"//"&References!C10&"//"&References!C11`

But i need that those cell coordenates changes by another cell number. For example, if i have the value "7" in the cell "K2" it should be something like this

`="&References!B(K2)&"//"&References!B(K2+1)&"//"&References!B(K2+2)&"//"&References!B(K2+3)&"//"&References!B(K2+4)&"&mejor="&References!C(K2)&"//"&References!C(K2+1)&"//"&References!C(K2+2)&"//"&References!C(K2+3)&"//"&References!C(K2+4)`

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Wow Alvaro, it looks complicated, but it isn´t.

If you want to get the cell content with a given row or column within another cell, you could use `=INDIRECT(ADDRESS(row,col))`

So if you want to get the value of `=References!B7` you could also do `=References!INDIRECT(ADDRESS(7,2))`.

Please note that `B7` is `ADDRESS(7,2)` (so row = 7, col = 2). For columns, you must use numbers instead of letters.

Following with what you intend to do: if K2 value is 7, meaning row 7 to get cells from B7 to B10 and C7 to C10, it would be easy to build the formula you want

`=Concatenate(References!INDIRECT(ADDRESS(K2,2)), "//", References!INDIRECT(ADDRESS(K2+1,2)), "//", References!INDIRECT(ADDRESS(K2+2,2)), "//", References!INDIRECT(ADDRESS(K2+3,2)). "//", References!INDIRECT(ADDRESS(K2+4,2)), "//","&mejor=", References!INDIRECT(ADDRESS(K2,3)), "//", References!INDIRECT(ADDRESS(K2+1,3)), "//", References!INDIRECT(ADDRESS(K2+2,3)), "//", References!INDIRECT(ADDRESS(K2+3,3)), "//", References!INDIRECT(ADDRESS(K2+4,3))`

Notice string concatenation looks nicer if you use the Concatenate() function.

If this solves your question, please don´t forget to mark this as the answer.

Comment: Doesnt work. Looks like Addresss works in a different way

Comment: Could you please share your excel sheet and code? I tried this code inside https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets and it works without any problems.